# Spark file load - `try` and `except` in scala

Tags: json, scala

I wish to read a file that is in one of two locations. I wish to try the first location and if this fails, try the second location. In python I would use a `try` and then if a `IOError` `file does not exist` is returned use `except` for the second location. I can read one location in scala like this:

```
val vertices_raw = sqlContext.read.json("location_a/file.json")
```

I have tried the following, using getOrElse:

```
val vertices_raw = sqlContext.read.json("location_a/file.json") getOrElse vertices_raw = sqlContext.read.json("location_b/file.json")
```

However this did not compile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the same thing in Scala

```
val vertices_raw: DataFrame = try {
  sqlContext.read.json("location_a/file.json")
} catch {
  case e: Exception => sqlContext.read.json("location_b/file.json")
}
```

Or alternatively

```
import scala.util.Try

val vertices_raw = 
  Try(sqlContext.read.json("location_a/file.json"))
    .getOrElse(sqlContext.read.json("location_b/file.json"))
```

Comment: Thanks Mustafa! However for the second version I am getting `not found: value Try`. Is there something I must `import`? seems strange...

Comment: `import scala.util.Try`

Comment: `vertices_raw` doesn't need to be a `var`

Comment: Thanks! Quick follow up. Why does this not extend to the following? 

```val local_input = "a.json" 
val other_input = "b.json" val input_file = Try(local_input).getOrElse(local_input) ```
In the case where the first fails, it is unable to fall back on the second

Comment: Is there a way to use Success, Failure and match without the need to nest? I like your approach though.

Comment: I don't think I understand your question @Brian